# application starts in black screen - no view visible

Tags: android, cordova, view

I'm trying to setup a simple view onto the root of phoneGap but i get black screen.

This is the code of a class to inflate and load from xml:

```
    public TopBar(Context context){
        myActivity = (Activity)context;
    }

    protected View createTopBarView() {

        RelativeLayout mainLayout = new RelativeLayout(myActivity);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        LayoutInflater inflater = myActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_bar, null);
        topBarView = (LinearLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutTopBar);

        /**
         * Setting Buttons....
         */




//Adding the View
        mainLayout.addView(topBarView);
        return mainLayout;
    }
```

The method returns a view, and in a class that extneds droidGap i do:

```
private void createLayout(){

    mainRelative = new RelativeLayout(this);
    mainRelative.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

    View topBarView = new TopBar(this).createTopBarView();
    mainRelative.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mainRelative.addView(topBarView);

    root.addView(mainRelative);


}
```

This function is called from onCreate, But i get a black screen when running.

Comment: what do you mean by "onto the root of phonegap"?

Comment: I've meant this line:
    root.addView(mainRelative);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try to add

```
mainLayout.addView(layout);
```

instead of

```
mainLayout.addView(topBarView);
```

I might to help

EDIT:
Have you done this: `setContentView(yourLayout, LayoutParams);` in onCreate?

Comment: i've changed to 'layout' but it didnt help.
no i didnt done setContentView.

Comment: Please setContentView, so you will be able to bind your layout to Activity